# ignore folder in eslint react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I'm developing an application using React and eslint. My problem is that inside my projects `src` folder there is an 'api-client' folder. Inside this folder are auto generated files used for managing connection to back-end. My problem is that every time I run or make changes to the app I see lots of errors inside the console regarding `no-unused-vars` and similar. Is there a way to ignore this folder completely? I can't move it outside of the `src` folder. I'm ignoring this folder in `.eslintignore` file with the line `/src/api-client/*`. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to add `/src/api-client/**` to your `.eslintignore` to disable eslint for ALL files in the `api-client` folder (and any files in deeper folders)

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically tell ESLint to ignore specific files type

1. Ignore the folder `/src/folder-name`
2. Ignore the folder and everything inside it `/src/folder-name/**`
3. Ignore the folder and everything inside it of special file type `/src/folder-name/**/*.js`

Comment: this does ignore the files inside `eslint`. But my problem is that those files are still parsed when I run `npm start` and they give out errors like `no-unused-vars` and such. I'm trying to ignore the folder for this case

Comment: paste your npm start command from package.json, looks like a mismatch

Comment: the command looks like this `"start": "npm-run-all start-js"`

Comment: oh okay so you need to paste your scripts like this 
{
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "rimraf dist",
        "lint":  "eslint src",
        "build": "babel src -o lib"
    }
}
what is the value of "lint" in your case?

Comment: there is no `eslint` there. Again when the project is started with `npm start` or recompiled when changes are made I see wall of warning that are coming from `api-client` folder inside `src`, I need to ignore this folder.

Comment: this is only possible if, your `.eslitignore` file is not picked by ESLint, and if you are using VSCode plugin then I guess it is ignoring them in VSCode but your CLI isn't
can you please confirm if your `.eslintignore` is in the same folder, how are you able to lint without actually calling it from your package.json

Comment: can you please type this and test 
`eslint --ignore-pattern '/src/api-client/**'`

Comment: yes, my `.eslintignore` is in the root of the project. furthermore when I run a code inspection the folder is successfully ignored.

Comment: I'm using WebStorm and it picks up the file automatically so no need for a command

Comment: please paste your start-js, there must be eslint calling there

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a specific solution but this worked for me.

I needed to disable some react-app rules in a specific folder. So I added this in my packages.json and it ignores the folder. Not sure if there was a way to disable all rules maybe "*" but not sure.

```
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app",
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": [
      "src/modules/template/*"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  }
]
```

},

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` add the following:

```
"eslintIgnore": [
  "path/**/*.ts"
],
```